# String to double array

Tags: vb.net, arrays, string, double, paramarray

I need to take this string:

```
Dim tmpTry As String = "10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 52, 20, 20, 10, 35, 3, 8, 47, 7, 2, 5, 55, 8, 0, 0, 6, 55, 0, 2, 12, 0, 0, 21, 14, 0, 3"
```

And convert it to a double array:

```
Dim arrNumOfVisits As Double() = New Double(tmpTry) {}
```

How do i go about doing that?

FYI the arrNumOfVisits goes into a **ParamArray System.Collections.IEnumerable()**

David

Comment: Have you looked into using Regex?

Comment: RegEX is beyound my comprehension...

Comment: I'm not going to be able to offer a total solutions because I'm not that great at Regex, or vb.net (I use c#), but this may get you looking the right direction:  "string[] numbers = Regex.Split(input, @"\D+");"  gets you an array of strings that are numbers separated by non-numbers.  Perhaps a simple cast to double will work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim arrString As String() = tmpTry.Split(New Char() {" "C})
Dim arrNumOfVisits As Double() = New Double(arrString.Length) {}
Dim i As Integer = 0
While i < arrString.Length
    arrNumOfVisits(i) = Double.Parse(arrString(i))
    i += 1
End While
```

The above code will do the trick, using regEx on this would be overkill.

Never the less do try to learn the basic RegEx operations, here are my favorite cheat sheets:
http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1
http://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/